# Connection Between Java App and Sql Server EXPR 2008 R2 Not Established

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, mssql-jdbc

I'm newbie with SQL Server , i'm trying to connect my java Application to SQL Server, actually i get the JDBC jar file for MSSQL Driver from [Microsoft Offical website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774)
then as showing in my [Screenshot Here*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bHOz.png) the SQL Server Driver was imported well, but m problem i faced that i got this Exception while i pretty sure that i did the required steps well.

## Error output :

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:TOSHIBA-PC;database=xxx;user=sa@TOSHIBA-PC;password=shiner151092;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;loginTimeout=30;
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at connect.main(connect.java:18)
C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

> where is the Problem and how could i solve it?
>
> **Class connect's code**:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class connect {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        String connectionString =
            "jdbc:sqlserver://TOSHIBA-PC;"
            + "database=xxx;"
            + "user=sa@TOSHIBA-PC;"
            + "password=shiner151092;"
            + "encrypt=true;"
            + "trustServerCertificate=false;"
            + "loginTimeout=30;";

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString)) {


            String selectSql = "SELECT * from Table_111";
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSql)) {

                            if(resultSet != null){
                                System.out.println("connection goes right !!!");
                            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `jdbc:TOSHIBA-PC;...` is not a valid JDBC URL. Check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx): Format for MS SQL JDBC URL is `jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]`. For you, that would mean: `jdbc:sqlserver://TOSHIBA-PC;...`

Comment: @Andreas Also through the UI interface Connection doesn't goes to be established dude :)

Comment: @Andreas, between if u cehck to connection example section its say this 
`#Connection Examples
Connect to the default database on the local computer by using a user name and password:
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=MyUserName;password=*****;`

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying. Your error is cause by the missing `sqlserver://` part of the URL. No clue as to what "UI interface Connection" or "connection example section" you're referring to, not that it matters. I've told you what you did wrong. Fix it and try again.

Comment: Add the complete code example just to give smb a chance to improve it.

Comment: @Andreas: And Now through the Ui same problem https://s21.postimg.org/ucniyz1zr/image.png

Comment: @42n4 Post Updated with the connect class code !!
then here the error i got when i'm trying using the connector Interface
>https://s21.postimg.org/ucniyz1zr/image.png

Comment: Your new "Cannot establish connection" is *not* the same thing as your original "No suitable driver found". The problem you posed in the question has been solved. Ask a new question, where you *don't* post screenshots, but enter or copy/paste your code and any error messages you.

Comment: @Andreas but i think now i have all detail problem, if you have solution drop it